# How can I restrict access to a static HTML page served from a subfolder of my site to authenticated users only?

Tags: files

I have a Drupal 8 site that has all roles and permissions necessary for authenticated users. One of the new requirements is to serve a static microsite (like a campaign site, totally different design compare to Drupal site) which is a single folder with all the static assets (HTML, CSS, JS , images). We have to serve this site under the same domain drupal is hosted and should be accessed ONLY by authenticated users.

I tried to host it under `sites/default/files/` directory, but it means it is public and anyone can access it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options to achieve this is using drupal's private file system. Drupal core out-of-box provides a way to access private files in a secured URL. Here are the steps:

1. upload the directory (e.g. `foo-bar`) to drupal's private file scheme. (you can find it under  Administration->Configuration->Media->File system)
2. Create a [hook_file_download($uri)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.8.x) in a custom module and check for necessary access conditions:

   ```
   function mymodule_file_download($uri) {

     // Check user permission only if the requested
     // file is under foo-bar directory. 
     if (strpos($uri, 'foo-bar') !== FALSE) {
       if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
         return -1
       }

       // Return a header to inform access is granted.
       return ['Cache-Control' => 'private'];
     }
   }
   ```
3. Now the directory is available for authenticated users at `www.example.com/system/files/foo-bar/index.html`.

Check [Drupal\system\FileDownloadController::download()](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/8.8.x/core/modules/system/src/FileDownloadController.php#L73) for more details

This would work for both Drupal 8 & 9. I haven't checked 7.