# How to use custom HTML code for a front page

Tags: 8

I want to use custom HTML code for a front page in drupal 8 but I am a bit lost of how to do it. Is it possible to just insert a piece of HTML code in a basic page content? Or what is the best way to do it? I have full access to the server and I can modify any file if needed.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/293828/how-can-i-restrict-access-to-a-static-html-page-served-from-a-subfolder-of-my-si

Answer (score 1):

You can make any node be the front page. So, if you have a basic page with a body field, you can place your html there. Then, go to admin > configuration > system (basic site settings) and set the path to your node as the front page such as /node/6.